# How get access to Uart port on Android?

Tags: android, uart, raspberry-pi4, lineageos

There is a Raspberry Pi 4 with Lineage OS Android version 10 installed. How can I access the uart port and read/send data?

With the library com.google.android.things the application is not installed, the error INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_LIBRARY is returned. If I register it in the manifest it doesn't work anyway, a crash of RuntimeException("Stub!") occurs.
The SerialUsb library sees 0 available drivers.
Trying to read via stream - file not found or permission denied. Even if the application is installed in system/app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.